# Странный баг или почему это случилось со мной

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть проблемы такова: есть программа, имитирующая работу светофора. Используется паттерн MVP. Существует 3 типа светофора : пешеходный, дорожный для дороги А, дорожный для дороги В. Для дорожных светофоров 2 объекта одного класса, для пешеходного свой класс. Эти классы унаследованы от базового класса. Сам баг заключается в том, что визуально( на форме, рисунке) мигают только дорожный  светофор дороги  А и пешеходный светофор. Наблюдая за работой участков кода, отвечающих за это, заметил что все работает правильно, ставил MessageBox`ы в тех местах где должно производится мигание, месседжбокс срабатывал но отрисовка мигания дорожного светофора В не видно.

Вот базовый класс:

```
    abstract class TrafficLight:ITrafficLight
    {         
        public event UpdateEvent UpdateState;

        public Statelight CurrentState;
        protected int TLStateIndex;
        protected ITLController TLController;
        protected TlType Type=TlType.B;
        public Timer BlinkingTimer = new Timer(300);
        public bool flag = false;

        public TrafficLight(ITLController Tlc,  TlType Type)  
        {
            this.Type = Type;
            this.TLController = Tlc;
            Tlc.Subscribe(this);           
            BlinkingTimer.Elapsed += Blink;

        }

        public void Notify(int StIndex, ITLController c)
        {

            TLStateIndex = StIndex;
            UpdateState(SetColor(StIndex, c), this.Type);

            if (c.GetState(this.Type) == Statelight.FG || c.GetState(this.Type) == Statelight.FY)
            {
                BlinkingTimer.Start();
                //if(Type == TlType.B)
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(StIndex+" "+Type);

            }
            else  BlinkingTimer.Stop();                
        }

        public abstract bool[] SetColor(int StIndex, ITLController c);
        public abstract void Blink(object sender, EventArgs e);
    }
```

Вот код класса - наследника, со вторым экземпляром которого(дорожный светофор В) и происходит такая чихурда:

```
    class CarTL:TrafficLight
    {
        bool[] Lamps = new bool[4];
        public bool BlinkOnOff = true;

        public CarTL(ITLController Tlc, TlType Type) : base(Tlc, Type) { }

        public override bool[] SetColor(int StIndex, ITLController c)
        {
            CurrentState = c.GetState(Type);

            switch (CurrentState)
            {
                    // green flashing yellow red
                case Statelight.FG:  Lamps[0] = BlinkOnOff;  Lamps[1] = true;  Lamps[2] = false; Lamps[3] = false; break;
                case Statelight.G:   Lamps[0] = true;  Lamps[1] = false; Lamps[2] = false; Lamps[3] = false; break;
                case Statelight.FY:  Lamps[0] = false; Lamps[1] = true;  Lamps[2] = BlinkOnOff;  Lamps[3] = false; break;
                case Statelight.off: Lamps[0] = false; Lamps[1] = false; Lamps[2] = false; Lamps[3] = false; break;
                case Statelight.R:   Lamps[0] = false; Lamps[1] = false; Lamps[2] = false; Lamps[3] = true; break;
                case Statelight.RY:  Lamps[0] = false; Lamps[1] = false; Lamps[2] = true;  Lamps[3] = true; break;
                case Statelight.Y:   Lamps[0] = false; Lamps[1] = false; Lamps[2] = true;  Lamps[3] = false; break;

            }

            //if (Type.Equals(TlType.A) && CurrentState.Equals(Statelight.FG)) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Lamps[0]+" "); }

            return Lamps;
        }

        public override void Blink(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BlinkOnOff = !BlinkOnOff;

            this.Notify(TLStateIndex, TLController);
            if (this.Type == TlType.B) 
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("  "+BlinkOnOff);
            }            
        }    
    }
```

Все данные проходят через презентер и приходят на форму для отрисовки, вот код где запускается отрисовка:

```
public partial class TLView : Form, WinFormsTrafficLights.ITLDisplay
{

    event ViewUpdate Update;
    public TlType TypeTL;
    public IPresenter TLViewPresenter;
    protected Brush[] BrushM;

    public TLView()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();

        Update += new ViewUpdate(Output);
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        BrushM = TLViewPresenter.GetInfo(this.TypeTL);
        Update();
    }

    void Output()
    {
        if (TypeTL == TlType.P)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalidate B");
        }
        Invalidate();           
    }

}
```

Вот ссылка на сам проект, кому не сложно посмотрите, мб кто-то уже сталкивался с таким багом. Уже 3 дня бьюсь над этой проблемой..
[Ссылка на проект](http://www.ex.ua/view_storage/792767206092)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Беда у вас в файле Presenter.cs строки 132-136:

```
        else
        {//disabled
            TLBBrush[0] = Brushes.Gray;//Было TLABrush[0]
            TLBBrush[1] = Brushes.Gray;//Было TLABrush[1]
            TLBBrush[2] = Brushes.Gray;//Было TLABrush[2]
        }
```

Почему так разбираться не стал, слишком много букв! сложно вы пишете.

Но одно сказать могу точно - копи паст это не выход... Делайте лучше модель.
Потом, не брезгуйте стандартом VS по форматированию и именованию переменных - проще жить будет.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое))) Даже подумать не мог что все сдесь окажется))
Вот как трезвый взгляд со стороны помогает в программировании))
Буду стараться не повторять своих ошибок )

Comment: Относительно того почему это случилось с Вами: меньше копипаста. Уменьшайте избыточность кода. ну и т.д. - не стесняйтесь делать рефактор в мелочах. Потом проще жить будет